# Xutility conflicts with regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I am having an issue using regex in my c++ project. By including the regex file I get 25 errors in the xutility file, and I'm not really sure why.

the include decleration

```
#include <regex>
```

The errors
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwr3M.jpg)

The Lines of xutility those errors correspond to:

```
        // TEMPLATE CLASS iterator_traits
 template<class _Iter>
struct iterator_traits
{   // get traits from iterator _Iter
typedef typename _Iter::iterator_category iterator_category;
typedef typename _Iter::value_type value_type;
typedef typename _Iter::difference_type difference_type;
typedef difference_type distance_type;  // retained
typedef typename _Iter::pointer pointer;
typedef typename _Iter::reference reference;
};
```

For some reason these errors only occur if I call a regex, the regex file can be imported and I can make a regex, but if I build with the regex being used the errors come

Comment: aaaand what have you tried to fix it? What version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue with using a character array for the match,

[Can regex be used with a character array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321324/can-regex-be-used-with-a-character-array-in-c)

for the specifics