# Can regex be used with a character array in C++

Tags: c++, regex, arrays, char

I'm working on a program that cannot use the string library file, instead I am using char arrays. I am able to use regex, and was wondering if there is a way to use regex and character arrays, or even regex and a single char?

The reason why I ask is when I attempt to use my char array in a match the xUtility throws a bunch of errors from the "TEMPLATE CLASS iterator_traits"

```
if(regex_match(userCommand[3], userCommand[8], isNumeric))
```

errors:

[image: Compiler error messages]

Comment: If you can use regexes, you can assuredly use `std::string`. And regex for a single char is just, kinda, moronic...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: It's perfectly answerable. It's not even that bad a question. It's just a rather silly requirement.

Comment: You can always use the glibc regex functions (`regexec` etc.). They are C functions and thus work on char arrays.

Comment: If you're getting errors and you want help fixing them, you need to construct a [testcase](http://sscce.org). Don't just dump a single line of code with no context whatsoever, and a screenshot of 25 errors in your IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) and its friends work through iterators (as well as overloads for not only `const std::string&` but `const char*`).

So, yes, you can absolutely use a character array rather than `std::string`. I advise reading the documentation.

---

Per your edit:

> ```
> if(regex_match(userCommand[3], userCommand[8], isNumeric))
> ```

If `userCommand` is the array, then you are passing in two `char`s, not pointers ("iterators").

Try:

```
if(regex_match(&userCommand[3], &userCommand[8], isNumeric))
```

or:

```
if(regex_match(userCommand + 3, userCommand + 8, isNumeric))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of the pointer because the errors were coming up in the xUtility file

Comment: @Dave: A common pitfall with templates.